# how to Deploy farm solutions in release mode

Tags: 2010, solution-deployment, farm-solution

how to deploy farm solutions in sharepoint 2010 farm in release mode

1. Package the solutions in Release configuration.
2. Deploy farm solutions in Retail mode

Comment: Publish in release mode and then deploy.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because exam type questions are off topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to:

1. Change the Mode to 'Release'

[image]

2. Publish the solution to a location.

[image]
[image]

3. Use the Add-SPSolution, Install-SPSolution in Power-shell for deployment

Comment: What version of VS are these screenshots from? I'm in 2010 and it doesn't look like this.

Comment: @ErinL I'm on VS 2013

Comment: in visual studio 10 it can be ?